# How to fix NoReverseMatch at / in django

Tags: django

I Want To Fix This Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'register' not found. 'register' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'register' not found. 'register' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 660
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.0
Python Path:    
['D:\\Learning\\Work\\Djngo\\todo_app',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 4 Dec 2019 05:07:28 +0000
```

In This Line I'm Getting Error:

```
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Signup</a>
</li>
```

When i see if user is login and if he type this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register he can also go to register page so i don't need that

so that's why i add if statement to my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from todo import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

if User.is_authenticated:
    urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.index,name='index'),
        path('accounts/logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    ]   
else:
    urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.index,name='index'),
        path('accounts/register',views.signup,name='register'),
        path('accounts/login/', LoginView.as_view(), {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}, name='login'),
    ]
```

But When i add this i'm getting that error please help me!

Error Screenshot:

[image]

Here is my views.py

```
def login_user(request, template_name='registration/login.html', extra_context=None):  
    cap = None
    reg2 = None
    ###############################
    if requests.method == 'POST':
        recaptcha_response = requests.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
        values = {
            'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
            'response': recaptcha_response
        }
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode()
        req =  urllib.request.Request(url, data=data)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        result = json.loads(response.read().decode())
        ''' End reCAPTCHA validation '''

        if result['success']:
            cap = True
        else:
            cap = False


    return render(requests,'login.html',{'cap':cap,})


# Create your views here.
def index(requests):
    return render(requests,'index.html')

def signup(requests):
    cap = None
    reg2 = None
    ###############################
    if requests.method == 'POST':
        reg = register(requests.POST)


        recaptcha_response = requests.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
        values = {
            'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
            'response': recaptcha_response
        }
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode()
        req =  urllib.request.Request(url, data=data)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        result = json.loads(response.read().decode())
        ''' End reCAPTCHA validation '''

        if result['success']:
            cap = True
            if reg.is_valid():
                if cap == True:
                    user = reg.save(commit=False)
                    user.set_password(User)
                    user.save()
                    reg2 = True

            else:
                print(reg.errors)


        else:
            cap = False

    else:
        reg = register()

    return render(requests,'signup.html',{'reg':reg,'cap':cap,'reg2':reg2,})
```

Here is my **base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/custom/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">TODO</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">New Task</a>
              </li>    
            </ul>
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-right">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">welcome: {{request.user}}</a>
                    </li>     
                </ul>
            {% else %}
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-right">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Signup</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                    </li>     
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=_reCAPTCHA_site_key"></script>
    {% block content_block %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

The Error is in my base.html!

Comment: remove your if User.is_authenticated: from urls and add it  in templates

Comment: but if user is login he can go to register page i don't need that so that's why i add this id statement!

Comment: that you can do in templates, remove the if clause and check whether the error is there

Comment: but if i remove user can go with url!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the if-else condition from the your urls, and check if user is authenticated in your signup view. If user is authenticated, then redirect the user to some other url. Here the user will be redirected to the index page.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from todo import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

    urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.index,name='index'),
        path('accounts/logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
        path('',views.index,name='index'),
        path('accounts/register',views.signup,name='register'),
        path('accounts/login/', LoginView.as_view(), {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}, name='login'),
    ]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse


def signup(requests):
    if requests.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(reverse('index'))

    cap = None
    reg2 = None
    ###############################
    if requests.method == 'POST':
        reg = register(requests.POST)


        recaptcha_response = requests.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
        values = {
            'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
            'response': recaptcha_response
        }
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode()
        req =  urllib.request.Request(url, data=data)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        result = json.loads(response.read().decode())
        ''' End reCAPTCHA validation '''

        if result['success']:
            cap = True
            if reg.is_valid():
                if cap == True:
                    user = reg.save(commit=False)
                    user.set_password(User)
                    user.save()
                    reg2 = True

            else:
                print(reg.errors)


        else:
            cap = False

    else:
        reg = register()

    return render(requests,'signup.html',{'reg':reg,'cap':cap,'reg2':reg2,})
```

Docs: [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse), [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Comment: I'm Getting this error `NameError at /accounts/register
name 'request' is not defined
`

Comment: fixed, i missed the variable name that you were using.

Comment: Thanks For Answering Me! Upvoted You, And Answer Accepted, Nice Answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are having this issue because you have different `urlpatterns` based on if `User` is auth or not. When you have user auth, you don't have `register` url name, hence you get error with url resolving.

Proper way to fix this and prevent user from accessing those pages is to make 2 changes:

Set [**redirect_authenticated_user**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) in django contrib auth views. Logout view is fine on it's own since it will work the same both for auth and not auth users.
**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from todo import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('accounts/logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('accounts/register',views.signup,name='register'),
    path('accounts/login/', LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}, name='login'),
]
```

Redirect user in your own views:
**views.py:**

```py
def signup(requests):
    if requests.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(reverse('index'))
    # ...
```